# Soft filling (wrap) in Auctex

Tags: editors, auctex

Auctex has a nice feature that fills the paragraph (`LaTeX-fill-paragraph`) based on emacs' `fill-column`. This as you know extends to environments as well (`C-c C-q C-e`). This works fine for me when I write alone, however, when I work with colleagues who doesn't use emacs necessary, it becomes problematic.

My coauthors often complains that my latex code dictates *my* column width to them. Other editors has a soft-wrap functionality that *looks* like a newline in the editor but there is no real newline.

Is there a way, that I could have Auctex to fill paragraph but doesn't insert actual new lines?

Comment: You are probably looking for [Visual Line Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html), which is an Emacs feature, rather than AUCTeX's.

Comment: The other way around could be for the coauthors to realize that having shorter lines, makes backwards-search more precise (I know texstudio has some extra tricks but it still stands)

Comment: If you use indentation (with spaces) and want the later parts of wrapped lines indented too you may additionally want to consider `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` (for which you need to install the [`adaptive-wrap`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/adaptive-wrap.html) package). It doesn't work with actual tabs (but can be made to).

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to the `.emacs` file worked for me:

```
(require 'mode-local)
(defvar-mode-local tex-mode fill-column 1000000 "")
```

It basically increases the fill-column size to a large value (only in the tex-mode).

A minimal example using `use-package`:

```
(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex
  :if (display-graphic-p)
  :defer t
  :mode
  ("\\.tex\\'" . tex-mode)
  :config
  ;; Avoids column fill when formatting
  (require 'mode-local)
  (defvar-mode-local tex-mode fill-column 1000000 ""))
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please, can you post a full minimal working example to see your solution? Thank you very much.